# Static library with SocketIO Swift podfile

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, static-libraries

I would like to create a static library that using "SocketIO swift" in the podfile, when building the static library was encounter an error that the socketIO not found like [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f14wa.png)

Following is my podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'visitor_sdk' do pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift' end
```

May I know how to create static library with the podfile?

Comment: See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, may i know how it help to my problem? My problem is happen when I create the cocoapods but the pulled file from pod is not found (the pull file is working fine if I compile for application). possible you may provide the step if the reference may help my problem? thanks